Installing lib32gcc1
I have a problem when trying to install lib32gcc1, this is the error I get when I'm trying to install E: Unable to locate package lib32gcc1
what can I do?

What is the actual issue that you are trying to solve, and how did you decide that you needed this package? Did you perhaps mean lib32gcc-s1

The closest you can get to lib32gcc1 in Ubuntu 24.04 is lib32gcc-s1 (GCC support library (32 bit Version)). Open the terminal and type:
sudo apt install lib32gcc-s1

Description: GCC support library (32 bit Version)
 Shared version of the support library, a library of internal  
subroutines  that GCC uses to overcome shortcomings of particular  
machines or special needs for some languages.

